# Snake game draw array function

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I have followed a YouTube video and there’s a part of a code I can’t understand. Hope you guys can help me out.

The array is for the snake body.

```
Public void Draw()
{
    for (int i = Body.length - 1; i > 0; i- -)
        Body[i] = Body[i - 1];
}
```

What does this code do?

Answer (score 3):

I assume Body is an array indicating all the positions of the snake, starting with the first.  This loop says that for every position in the array representing the positions of the snake (starting with the endmost moving to the front), set it to be the previous.  The end result is the exact same array as before, except every position is moved down the line one.

Notice the order is important here.  If you started from position 1 in the array, you would assign Body[1] to the value of Body[0], and on the next step, Body[2] to the value of Body[1], et cetera until the entire array is overridden with the initial value in Body[0].

In fact "Draw" is a somewhat misleading name for a method in this case, since it's updating the snake rather than "drawing" the snake as it would lead you to think.

Comment: It's the opposite. `Body[i] = Body[i - 1]` means that _you would assign Body[99] to Body[100], and on the next step, Body[98] to Body[99], et cetera_. Your answer also missed the point of a **decreasing for loop**, which makes your example less applicable here and invalidates your final conclusion ("until the entire array is overridden with the initial value in Body[0]" is not correct, the code is correctly shifting all points by one index, it's not overwriting everything with the same value)

Comment: @Flater By "assign Body[1] to Body[0]" I meant "assign Body[1] to the value of Body[0]".  Also the conclusion "until the entire array is overridden with the initial value in Body[0]" is what would happen if the order were reversed.  Please reread with the previous correction in mind.  Edited for clarity.  My apologies for any misinterpretation.

Comment: Why are you answering about what would happen **if** the for loop wasn't reversed? The question is what the OP's code snippet accomplishes, not what a slightly different code snippet would accomplish. For this specific case, the order of operations is important to a point where a normal for loop would be nonsensical.

Comment: @Flater Because traditionally you see loops start from 0 and move up.  OP is having difficulties understanding the loop, and I think it is worth mentioning why the loop counts down, though the same could be accomplished counting up, but only if you also change the inner command to `Body[i - 1] = Body[i]`.  I figure I'd prefer to err by having explained too much rather than too little.  Again, my apologies.